# Secure Inbound/Outbound Rules for EC2 Instance with Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Elastic Beanstalk environment with a Classic Load Balancer.

I'm trying to make the Inbound/Outbound Rules for my EC2 instances as secure as possible.

So far, the most secure setting that has worked is:

Inbound -> All traffic -> from Load Balancer Security Group

Outbound -> All traffic -> from 0.0.0.0/0

This allows me to both deploy a new version of the app and make successful calls to the app from a browser.

However, it seems to me to be a little insecure. Is there a way to reduce the access without breaking the ability to deploy new versions/make calls to the app?

Comment: How does it seem insecure to you? What specifically is insecure here?

Comment: Thanks for commenting - I can't point to any specific issue. If someone owns my EC2 enough to send data from it, I probably have bigger problems. But I suppose my feeling is that you should only allow exactly as much access as is needed. To that end, shouldn't I be able to simply set an outbound rule IP range that covers the load balancer and whatever IP updates the app and nothing else?